# How to use KUKA experimental with ROS2 Foxy

Tags: ros, ros2, kuka, catkin, colcon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I want to control a KUKA LBR iiwa 14 with ROS2 Foxy and found the KUKA experimental package.

https://github.com/ros-industrial/kuka_experimental

The installation process is described in the ROS wiki.
http://wiki.ros.org/kuka_experimental
Unfortunately it uses `catkin_make` for the building and not `colcon` as it is recommended for ROS2.

Is there a workaround to use `colcon`? Or are there other ways to use this KUKA package under ROS2?

I appreciate every helpful answer :)

Thank you very much,
Nils

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/399802/how-to-use-kuka-experimental-with-ros2-foxy/) by [Nils](https://answers.ros.org/users/103470/nils/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-04-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aarsh_t](https://answers.ros.org/users/73435/aarsh_t/) on 2022-04-28**:
Unfortunately it seem like that package is yet to be migrate to the ros2 (Or might not be migrated to). And you can not use `colcon`  with the ros1 package AFAIK. But I think @gvdhoorn will have more insights on the kuka and ros-industrial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is no ROS 2 support in `kuka_experimental`.

Additionally, `kuka_experimental` does not support control of IIWAs. Sunrise controllers do not (really) support RSI nor EKI afaik.

You'll have to use other packages for that.

---

Edit: see [Ros2 support for KUKA iiwa](https://discourse.ros.org/t/ros2-support-for-kuka-iiwa/24735) for a recent ROS Discourse post about this.

I haven't used any of the packages mentioned in that thread, so I can't say anything as to their performance or stability.

Another option could be [kroshu/ros2_kuka_sunrise](https://github.com/kroshu/ros2_kuka_sunrise), but there are many more.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2022-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2